# Azure Application insights for web, display unique users in power BI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-application-insights, powerbi

We set up web analytics using `Application Insights -> Stream Analytics -> Power BI` path.

We would like to see the chart of daily unique visitors in Power BI dashboard.

Users are considered unique if `[context].[user].anonId` are different. Time is placed in `[context].[data].eventTime` in insights json.

The export query should look something like that (we know how to address missing `unique` keyword, so I'll use it for simplicity):

```
SELECT
    count(unique A.[context].[user].anonId)
    SYSTEM.TIMESTAMP
FROM
    [export-input] A
    TIMESTAMP BY A.[context].[data].eventTime
GROUP BY 
    TumblingWindow(day, 1)
```

The problem is `TIMESTAMP BY` does not support qualified fields. Without that, **we're actually timestamping users not by actual page visit time, but by the time this data entered stream analytics**. This means, we might loose a bunch of unique uesrs, or count some of them twice.

Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: So just to know -- our current query (considered to be buggy) perfectly matches distinct user count, displayed in azure portal. I suppose it's a bug.

Answer (score 1):

TIMESTAMP BY now supports qualified fields, so it should not be a problem anymore. However, please note that Stream Analytics does not have Unique/Distinct keyword. You will need to rewrite your query like this to compute unique count:

```
WITH step1 AS
(
SELECT
    COUNT(*) countPerAnonId
FROM
    [export-input] A
    TIMESTAMP BY A.[context].[data].eventTime
GROUP BY 
    A.[context].[user].anonId,
    TumblingWindow(day, 1)
)

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM step1
GROUP BY System.Timestamp
```

Comment: Shouldn't we group by `eventTime` in the last line?

Answer (score 0):

Could you, on the ASA side, just submit the 'view time' as a property of your event (from the client) and then select across that in ASA. I'm not that familiar with ASA's limits, but I can find someone to help if the above doesn't work.  In Power BI you can make Q&A queries like "show distinct anonID in the last 24 hours" or "... in the last day".  Which if there's a date field, should match your expected behavior.

Comment: Actually, it is impossible to do `TIMESTAMP BY [context].[data].eventime` as timestamp does not support qualified fields. So there's no possibility to do what you suggest